# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to figure out how to use reflection. I have set up 2 classes one has basic validation for numbers

```
public class Reflectee {

    String str;

    public Reflectee(String str){
        this.str=str;
    }

    public Reflectee(){

    }
    public boolean doSomething(String str){
        boolean flag=true;
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(str);
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){
            flag=false;
        }
        return flag;
    }
}
```

and then I have created a class that is going to use reflection to invoke doSomething method.

```
public class Reflector {

    private String str="22";

    public boolean reflect(){
        Reflectee r=new Reflectee();
        Class clazz=r.getClass();
        boolean b=false;
        try {
            Method m=clazz.getDeclaredMethod("doSomething",String.class);
            b=(Boolean)m.invoke(this,str); //Exception is here
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException |
                IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

I get an exception when I am trying to invoke a method the exception is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.app.example2.Reflector.reflect(Reflector.java:16)
    at com.app.example2.test.Reflector_UT.test(Reflector_UT.java:16)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I am sure that I am missing something minor. Any ideas what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

problem is on the following line

```
 b=(Boolean)m.invoke(this,str); //Exception is here
```

you have to invoke method on the Reflectee object rather than this(Reflector object)

```
 b=(Boolean)m.invoke(r,str); //Exception is here
```

Comment: That works however when I replace      b=(Boolean)m.invoke(this,str); with b=(Boolean)m.invoke(clazz,str); I still get an exception, why?

Comment: `m.invoke(r, str)` is equivalent to `r.doSomething(str)`. You cannot invoke doSomething method without an object of Relfectee class. Now `m.invoke(clazz, str)` is equivalent to `clazz.doSomething(str)` which obviously is wrong

Comment: Just an improvement suggestion on your comment: Using explicit variables would be more of a help for readers with less experience